# Django : "TypeError: unsupported operand type(s) for +: 'FloatField' and 'FloatField'"

Tags: python, django, django-models

> I am trying to add 2 models.FloatField variables in Django before saving the model, and getting an error.

```
    from django.db import models
    class MyModel(models.Model): 
        
        def __init__(self):
            self.value1 = models.FloatField(default=10.0)
            self.value2 = models.FloatField(default=20.0)
       
        def add_values(self):
            return self.value1 = self.value1 + self.value2
```

> When I create MyModel object and call add_values function, I get following error

```
    my_model = MyModel()
    my_model.add_values()
```

````
   **Error Stack**
   line 8, in add_values
   self.value1 = self.value1 + self.value2
   TypeError: unsupported operand type(s) for +: 'FloatField' and 'FloatField'```
````

Comment: Please check if this helps https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59181906/how-to-add-two-fields-of-django-model-and-save-the-sum-in-another-field

Comment: @SuryaTej Thanks a lot, this helps.
I had searched a lot for an issue similar to mine but could not find it before.

Comment: glad it helped :)

Answer (score 0):

You do not construct fields in the constructor, but at the model layer, so:

```
from django.db import models

class MyModel(models.Model): 
    value1 = models.FloatField(default=10.0)
    value2 = models.FloatField(default=20.0)
       
    def add_values(self):
        return self.value1 = self.value1 + self.value2
```

It might also be better to turn the `add_values` into a property:

```
from django.db import models

class MyModel(models.Model): 
    value1 = models.FloatField(default=10.0)
    value2 = models.FloatField(default=20.0)

    @property
    def sum_values(self):
        return self.value1 = self.value1 + self.value2
```